# Ubuntu 17.04 fails to connect to wifi on startup in Virtualbox

Tags: wireless, virtualization, 17.04

When loading up Ubuntu 17.04 on my VirtualBox, sometimes (Greater than 50% of the time), there will be no wifi in the machine, and I will usually have to restart the VM a few times to get wifi on startup. Sometimes it connects and sometimes it doesn't.

I tried to see if this was a problem with my desktop, so I tried using Ubuntu 16.04.2 and I have not had a problem with connecting to wifi with this version of Ubuntu. I'm also having the same issue on a completely different desktop, which is why I believe this is specifically a Ubuntu 17.04 problem. Has anyone else encountered this issue before?

I have wifi on my host machine and am using NAT, the default network configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue with 17.04.  My wifi connects automatically under 16.04 LTS.  As a workaround, I connect manually as a "Hidden Wifi Network".